# Books for learning the renormalization group

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, renormalization

Currently I'm learning about the renormalization group by Peskin and Schroeder, but I don't find its explanation totally clear. I know that the renormalization group is treated in many quantum field theory textbooks, such as

- "An Introduction To Quantum Field Theory"  by Peskin and Shroeder
- "The Quantum Theory of Fields"  by Weinberg
- "Quantum Field Theory"  by Itzykson and Zuber
- "Gauge Theory of elementary particle physics"  by Cheng and Li

Where can I find a clear explanation of the renormalization group in quantum field theory?

Comment: I know the renormalization group is a hard topic to understand in QFT. For example, [this post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/310862/an-analytic-continuation-of-the-one-loop-propagator-correction-in-yukawa-theory) hasn't yet receive any answer. (Probably it may also be the reason that people with adequate experience haven't looked at it.)  As a viewpoint, I think a book that has detailed explanations is a good book.

Comment: I recommend Nigel Goldenfeld's book "Lectures On Phase Transitions And The Renormalization Group" (Frontiers in Physics)

Comment: N. Goldenfeld. Lectures on Phase Transitions and the Renormalization
Group. Frontiers in Physics. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 1992.
isbn: 0-201-55409-7. Is worth a look. I would recommend it for scholars that have at least a basic idea of statistical thermodynamics.

Comment: Hi GotchaP. I have been studying QFT and many of your questions have been very helpful. I have made a QFT team on stackexchange and would like to have you in the team. Would you mind sharing your email address? Mine is petra.axolotl@gmail.com.